# mlDeploy task throwing error with gradle v3.16.4

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

On upgrading to ml-gradle v3.16.4 I am getting the below error while running the `mlDeploy` task.

`<error:format-string>MANAGE-INVALIDPAYLOAD: (err:FOER0000) Payload has errors in structure, content-type or values. Invalid payload: no such database: test-triggers</error:format-string>`

on googling it I found that this error has been fixed in `v3.16.3`.

Please find the related links below.

https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-app-deployer/commit/e6d9e2f5c0b09150f02d53f90265d69674ab0042

https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/issues/488

As per the above links I should not get the error.

Please help.

Comment: Please open a ticket in ml-gradle and attach the set of database files that you have.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reduce this to a minimal test case where the issue occurs in a clean build? If so, you should re-open the ticket in the ml-gradle github as a bug on 3.16.4.

There is also a workaround in the ticket:

"In the meantime, you can fix the problem by removing schema-database and security-database from each database file, as they'll default to Schemas and Security."

Does that work?